# Как поменять значение false на true в React, reducer

Tags: javascript, html5, reactjs, redux

Делаю TO-DO-LIST с помощью  React + Redux, и не могу понять, как правильно написать **CASE** что бы при нажатии на задание, у него менялось значение  **TRUE** на **FALSE** или наоброт с **FALSE** на **TRUE**.

```
import React from 'react'
import shortid from 'shortid';

const ADD_TASK = 'ADD_TASK'
const EDIT_STATUS = 'EDIT_STATUS'

const initialState = {
    tasks: [],
    chooseCurrentTaskStatus: 'all'
};


const mainReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case ADD_TASK: {
            let newTask = {
                id: shortid.generate(),
                task: action.task,
                status: false
            }
            return {
                ...state,
                tasks: [newTask, ...state.tasks]
            }
        }

        case EDIT_STATUS: {
            return {
                **ЧТО НАПИСАТЬ ЗДЕСЬ?**
            }
        }

    default:
        return state
    }
}

export const addTask = task => ({type: 'ADD_TASK', task});
export const editStatus = status => ({type: 'EDIT_STATUS', status})


export default mainReducer;
```

Answer (score 1):

Советую почитать документацию https://redux.js.org/basics/example

и вот пример, который решает вашу проблему.

```
case 'TOGGLE_TODO':
      return state.map(todo =>
        todo.id === action.id ? { ...todo, completed: !todo.completed } : todo
      )
```